# Wordpress , por que os plugins que instalo fica sem css e sem javascript?

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Olá. eu estou tentando colocar uma galeria de foto em um template wordpress que eu fiz, porém na hora que eu coloco o plugin ele insere o HTML em Páginas > Adicionar Página

E então adicionoi o código do plugin

```
[gallery_bank type="images" format="masonry" title="true" desc="false" responsive="true" display="selected" no_of_images="10" sort_by="random" animation_effect="" album_title="true" album_id="1"]
```

Porém ele só mostra o HTML, tanto o css e o javascript não funciona....

Tem que fazer alguma coisa no template para ele suportar plugins?

Informações adicionais é só pedir, preferi não entrar em muitos detalhes pois acredito que o problema é a falta de algum código para dar suporte a plugins.

Porém qualquer palpite ajuda a descobrir o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porque esta falando o [`wp_head()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_head) no `header.php` e o [`wp_footer()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) no `footer.php` do seu tema.

Essas funções são essenciais para o funcionamento correto do tema.

No codex do WordPress tem uma documentação comenta sobre isso em [Theme Developement](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development).